# Como aplicar el recolor de Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 en el tema Monokai pro de visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio

Quiero tener este recolor en los paréntesis, corchetes y llaves que tiene la extension Bracket Pair Colorizer 2, tengo entendido que ya viene por defecto en vscode pero solo en los temas ya preinstalados.
Estoy instalando esta extencion pero no se esta aplicando el recolor y sigue igual que antes, como podria modificarlo para que si se aplique en el tema que estoy usando que es el monokai pro.

Es decir quiero que se vean asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en lugar de asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado añadiendo lo siguiente al settings.json pero sigue sin funcionar:

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active",
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colors": [
    "Gold",
    "Orchid",
    "LightSkyBlue"
],
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.activeScopeCSS": [
    "borderStyle : solid",
    "borderWidth : 1px",
    "borderColor : {color}",
    "opacity: 0.5"
],
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.scopeLineCSS": [
    "borderStyle : solid",
    "borderWidth : 1px",
    "borderColor : {color}",
    "opacity: 0.5"
],
```